# How to set cross env variables to start tests before commit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, environment-variables

I have configured to run tests before commit. But it only works in Ubuntu.

Here what I have now:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:all": "CI=true react-scripts test"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run test:all"
    }
  },
```

How to set cross env variables to run them in any operating system?

Comment: you can try `"pre-commit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test &&  npm run test:all"`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package:

```
  "test:all": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with a .env.test file? See React docs for info on .env in create-react-app [create-react-app adding custom variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)